# Create a ruby hash with special characters in the key, new syntax

Tags: ruby

The new ruby syntax allows:

```
states = {
  Oregon: 'OR',
  Florida: 'FL',
  California: 'CA',
}
```

How could I add something like:

```
states = {
  New York: 'NY'
}
```

I get an error if I try `New\ York:` or `'New York':`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done in the new syntax.

Ruby's formal grammar unfortunately isn't documented anywhere, but the [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) shows that the parser expects a `tLABEL`, which means that keys in the new syntax must follow the same rules as Ruby identifiers.

Comment: Ruby identifiers consist of alphabets, decimal digits, and the underscore character, and begin with a alphabets(including underscore) --I wasn't clear on that offhand, so I'll post it for others.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use that syntax. Do this:

```
states = {
  :"New York" => "NY"
}
```

or

```
states = {
  "New York".to_sym => "NY"
}
```

Comment: You'd have to modify the ruby interpreter to fulfil the OP needs

Comment: Ok. Old syntax is fine, I just thought there might be a way built in.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it in the inverse order, then apply[`invert`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-invert) to flip it back:

```
states = {
  OR: :"Oregon",
  FL: :"Florida",
  CA: :"California",
  NY: :"New York"
}.invert
```

This has symbol keys and values, but you can always convert the values to strings as required.

The "new style" hash declarations are quite limited in the sort of keys you can define unless you use a more formal style like `:"New York" => '...'`.

Comment: What do you mean by `:"New York":`? That looks invalid to me.

Comment: @sawa Ah, you're right. I guess that'd be `:"New York" => ...`